# cmake generator expression for runtime output directory

Tags: cmake, cross-platform

Is there a generator expression for `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`?

I want to copy a directory to the runtime output directory, which I currently do like this:

```
 add_custom_target(copy_target ALL)
 add_custom_command(TARGET copy_target POST_BUILD
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo
      $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:other_target>/foo)
```

Just copying to `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` will not work for multi-config generators (Visual Studio, XCode) that create subdirectories for each configuration.

The example above works but it creates an unnecesary dependency of `copy_target` on `other_target`. I would prefer something like `${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_$<CONFIG>}` but this was not accepted (unexpected `<`). Also, the solution should work with single-config generators as well, which `${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_$<CONFIG>}` probably wouldn't.

Also `$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:copy_target>` does not work, because `copy_target` is a dummy, not a binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable [CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR.html) may be helpful, e.g.:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET copy_target POST_BUILD
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo
      ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/${CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR}/foo)
```

Answer (score 2):

I see that sakra answered your question, and I do not have a better answer to your specific question. But I do have a suggestion for simplifying working with both multi-configuration builds (for Visual Studio) and single-configuration builds (for Linux makefiles). I like to collapse the output directories to a flat structure with all configuration artifacts having unique postfixes so they do not collide. I do this with the following `init_output_directories` macro:

```
# initialize the variables defining output directories
#
# Sets the following variables:
#
# - :cmake:data:`CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`
# - :cmake:data:`CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`
# - :cmake:data:`CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`
#
# plus the per-config variants, ``*_$<CONFIG>``
#
# @public
#
macro(init_output_directories)

  # Directory for output files
  set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib 
    CACHE PATH "Output directory for static libraries.")

  set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib
    CACHE PATH "Output directory for shared libraries.")

  set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin
    CACHE PATH "Output directory for executables and DLL's.")

  foreach( OUTPUTCONFIG ${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES} )
    string( TOUPPER ${OUTPUTCONFIG} OUTPUTCONFIG )
    set( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin" CACHE PATH "" FORCE)
    set( CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib" CACHE PATH "" FORCE)
    set( CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib" CACHE PATH "" FORCE)
  endforeach()

endmacro()
```